# How to generate auto increment values column when select statement run in MY SQL?

Tags: mysql

How to display when i was run to find  duplicate values from my table at this time i want to add new column in select statement  with auto increment values

```
SELECT * FROM tutorials_tbl
WHERE Lscno IN (
SELECT Lscno
FROM tutorials_tbl
GROUP BY Lscno
HAVING COUNT(Lscno) > 1
)ORDER BY Lscno

ID       Title          LSCNo
10       titl_14    000000/06/3/1944
19       titl_13    000000/06/3/19
561     titl_1      000000/10/125/1955
671     titl_1      000000/10/125/1955
1765    titl_1      000000/06/65/1976
1834    titl_1      000000/06/65/1976
1909    titl_1      000000/06/3/1971
1910    titl_1      000000/06/3/1971

 **Excepted output like** in MY SQL ?




 Add
NewCol    ID    Title   LSCNo
  1       10    titl_14 000000/06/3/1944
  2       19    titl_13 000000/06/3/19
  3       561   titl_1  000000/10/125/1955
  4       671   titl_1  000000/10/125/1955
  5       1765  titl_1  000000/06/65/1976
  6       1834  titl_1  000000/06/65/1976
  7       1909  titl_1  000000/06/3/1971
  8       1910  titl_1  000000/06/3/1971
```

Comment: And where is your problem?

Comment: I want to display output like Above my expected output

Comment: And what is the output you get?

Comment: In my top of this question 14  record is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable. Something like:

```
SELECT @myCount:=@myCount+1 AS NewCol, ID, Title, LSCNo
FROM tutorials_tbl, (SELECT @myCount:= 0) t
WHERE Lscno IN (
    SELECT Lscno
    FROM tutorials_tbl
    GROUP BY Lscno
    HAVING COUNT(Lscno) > 1
)
ORDER BY Lscno
```

Comment: Thanks ,Then i want to add (LSCNo+NweCol)  format like this 000000/06/3/1944-1

Comment: You should checkout the **String Functions** from the reference resource http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html. Concatenate With Separator: CONCAT_WS() is what you want. I think CONCAT_WS('-', LSCNo, NewCol)

Answer (score 0):

Try following pseudo script:

```
select @a := ISNULL(@a, 0) + 1, *
from your_table;
```

This should solve your issue.