# Way to "create a primary key" in results of a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a unique question.  I have a table of random questions in a table called RandomQuestionBank.  I am going to be adding say 80 questions to this for a report to be generated every quarter, 20 per quarter.  I want to return 10 of those questions randomly on the report, which I can do using NEWID() and I do below

```
Select top 4 X_QuestionNumber,X_QuestionText,X_OrgID,X_PeriodLabel From XRandomQuestionBank 
Where X_PeriodLabel = Datepart(Quarter, getdate())
Order by NEWID()
```

The issue is that I'm creating a view to do this (long story, just needs to be a view). My results for above are.

```
X_QuestionNumber    X_QuestionText  X_OrgID X_PeriodLabel
1   This is question 1, qtr 4   22044   4
4   This is question 4, qtr 4   22044   4
3   This is question 3, qtr 4   22044   4
2   This is question 2, qtr 4   22044   4
```

The issue I am going to run into with this data is that if I expand this to return 10 rows, I am going to need X_QuestionNumber always to be sort of a primary key, so the above SHOULD look like the below every time, regardless of what questions/rows it actually pulls. The reason being if there are 20 questions and I pull 10, I'm going to get X_QuestionNumbers > 10.

```
X_QuestionNumber    X_QuestionText  X_OrgID X_PeriodLabel
1   This is question 1, qtr 4   22044   4
2   This is question 4, qtr 4   22044   4
3   This is question 3, qtr 4   22044   4
4   This is question 2, qtr 4   22044   4
```

I can't use row_number because that returns the row number before it's ordered by newID.  Is there anyway to just have a legit incrementing number in column 1?  Again I can't use the primary key of the randomquestionbank table either because it will also just be in non-sequential order.

Thanks!

Comment: `TOP` is an SQLServer syntax and NOT a MySQL syntax. Please be careful to tag correctly

Comment: Please look at this thread: [How to generate auto increment values column when select statement run in MY SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599037/how-to-generate-auto-increment-values-column-when-select-statement-run-in-my-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subquery your current query and generate a row number there:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP 4 X_QuestionNumber, X_QuestionText, X_OrgID, X_PeriodLabel
    FROM XRandomQuestionBank 
    WHERE X_PeriodLabel = DATEPART(Quarter, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X_QuestionNumber) X_QuestionNumber,
    X_QuestionText,
    X_OrgID,
    X_PeriodLabel
FROM cte
ORDER BY
     X_QuestionNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked, I had to make one small change.  Had to change Order BY X_QuestionNumber to NEWID in the second select.  Leaving it as-is just returned the top 4 questions each time